# PixiJs mask filter with background image

Tags: pixi.js

How can I create effect like on this site (work links)

https://monopo.london/work/

I was trying implement this example, but can't change black background with another image.

https://pixijs.io/examples/#/masks/filter.js

Please, HELP!

```
const app = new PIXI.Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Inner radius of the circle
const radius = 100;

// The blur amount
  const blurSize = 12;

app.loader.add('grass', 'https://images.prismic.io/monopolondon/abb53b73-caae-41d2-9031-f889aa27780d_onefinestay_thumb.jpeg?auto=compress,format&rect=0,0,1200,1436&w=600&h=718');
app.loader.load(setup);

function setup(loader, resources) {
    const background = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.grass.texture);
    app.stage.addChild(background);
    background.width = app.screen.width;
    background.height = app.screen.height;

    const circle = new PIXI.Graphics()
        .beginFill(0xFF0000)
        .drawCircle(radius + blurSize, radius + blurSize, radius)
        .endFill();
    circle.filters = [new PIXI.filters.BlurFilter(blurSize)];

    const bounds = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, (radius + blurSize) * 2, (radius + blurSize) * 2);
    const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(circle, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST, 1, bounds);
    const focus = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);
  console.log(texture);

    app.stage.addChild(focus);
    background.mask = focus;

    app.stage.interactive = true;
    app.stage.on('mousemove', pointerMove);

    function pointerMove(event) {
        focus.position.x = event.data.global.x - focus.width / 2;
        focus.position.y = event.data.global.y - focus.height / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already searched in https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/discussions and https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/issues  ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply adding some other Sprite to stage - before grass is added - like this:

- look at usage of `some_bg`

```
const app = new PIXI.Application();
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

// Inner radius of the circle
const radius = 100;

// The blur amount
const blurSize = 32;

app.loader.add('grass', 'examples/assets/bg_grass.jpg');
app.loader.add('some_bg', 'examples/assets/bg_plane.jpg');
app.loader.load(setup);

function setup(loader, resources) {
  
    const some_bg = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.some_bg.texture);
    some_bg.width = app.screen.width;
    some_bg.height = app.screen.height;
    app.stage.addChild(some_bg);
    console.log(some_bg);

  
  
    const background = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.grass.texture);
    app.stage.addChild(background);
    background.width = app.screen.width;
    background.height = app.screen.height;

    const circle = new PIXI.Graphics()
        .beginFill(0xFFFFFF)
        .drawCircle(radius + blurSize, radius + blurSize, radius)
        .endFill();
    circle.filters = [new PIXI.filters.BlurFilter(blurSize)];

    const bounds = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, (radius + blurSize) * 2, (radius + blurSize) * 2);
    const texture = app.renderer.generateTexture(circle, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.NEAREST, 1, bounds);
    const focus = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);

    app.stage.addChild(focus);
    background.mask = focus;

    app.stage.interactive = true;
    app.stage.on('mousemove', pointerMove);
  
    function pointerMove(event) {
        focus.position.x = event.data.global.x - focus.width / 2;
        focus.position.y = event.data.global.y - focus.height / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! 
Can I ask you about help with the same animation on hover from example?

Comment: please check this: https://codepen.io/domis86/pen/VwMQRGB
i added animation on 'mouseover' and 'mouseout'. You think you can continue from there?

Comment: Maybe you can help me with full example? Or take a link on documentation when I can research how can I reproduce the same functionality?